# Consuming Service Fabric ETW events outside Visual Studio

Tags: azure-service-fabric, etw

By default, ETW events produced by SF services are available through VS tooling. They are not available via Service Fabric Explorer. What are other (external to VS) tools can be used to consume those events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options here:

- Azure Diagnostics 
  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-diagnostics-how-to-setup-wad/
- the (preview) Service Profiler 
  https://www.azureserviceprofiler.com/
  (I think it works for Actors only at this time though, but it's already a very cool tool, worth having a look at)
- (as mentioned) Elastic Search 
  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-diagnostic-how-to-use-elasticsearch/

(etw data needs to be collected and transferred in every option)

Comment: Azure Service Profiler looks really good. And it covers the collection of the data. So that is the answer I was after, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Elastic Search or Kibana